# Deform a continuous mapping of $S^3$ into $G$ into a mapping into an $SU(2)$ subgroup of $G$.

Tags: algebraic-topology, lie-groups, homotopy-theory, gauge-theory

I am reading *The Uses of Instantons* (1977) by Sidney Coleman (a physics text!) and he quotes a pretty strong and useful claim:

> For a general simple Lie group $G$, any continuous mapping of $S^3$ into $G$ can be continuously deformed into a mapping into an $SU(2)$ subgroup of $G$.

**Question:** How do you prove this claim?

In his text, Coleman attributes this result to [Raoul Bott](http://www.numdam.org/item/?id=BSMF_1956__84__251_0), but looking at that paper (as a physicist) the only useful thing I can find is that $$\pi_3(G)=\mathbb{Z}$$ assuming a *simple*, *compact* Lie group. Is this enough to show the claim? How do you find the homotopy?

Comment: Every connected Lie group $G$ has a maximal compact subgroup $K$, and $G$ deformation retracts onto $K$; furthermore if $G$ is simple then so is $K$. So this lets us reduce to the compact case. In the compact case I don't believe that $\pi_3(K) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ is enough; what you want to show is that you can find a copy of $SU(2)$ inside $K$ such that the induced map $\pi_3(SU(2)) \to \pi_3(K)$ is an isomorphism. I believe this can be done using the Chevalley basis of the Lie algebra of $K$ but I don't know the details.

Comment: A connected simple Lie group $G$ may have non-simple maximal compact subgroup $K$, or worse, not even semisimple. For example $G=Sp(2n,R)$ and $K=U(n)$.

Comment: @Max: there's some disagreement about what "simple" ought to mean for Lie groups (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Lie_group) but I take your point. Fortunately $U(n)$ still satisfies $\pi_3(U(n)) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ (for $n \ge 2$) and that should still be true in general; I think we can take "simple" to mean connected + the Lie algebra is simple modulo its center, or something like that.

Comment: I don't think that the statement "simple compact groups have $\pi_3(K) = \mathbb{Z}$" can possibly imply that the same statement holds for simple Lie groups in general. For example, $G=SL(4,R)$ and $K=SO(4)$ which is locally isomorphic to $SO(3) \times SO(3)$, so that $\pi_3(SL(4,R))=\pi_3(SO(4)) = \mathbb{Z}^2$.